# How can I update the text "Signin / Register" of LoginComponent to "Login" in Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I would like to change the text in LoginComponent from "Signin/Register" to "Login". What is the best way to achieve this in Spartacus Storefront?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/#overwriting-individual-translations

You have to find the chunk + key in the source code, then provide your own translation for the given key